# Integrating React Auth Kit with Class-Based Components

Tags: reactjs

I've integrated React Auth Kit into my React application, which contains a mix of both functional and class-based components. The authentication works seamlessly with functional components using hooks. However, I'm struggling to integrate it with class-based components.

I have wrapped my entire app with the AuthProvider from React Auth Kit.
In functional components, I utilize the useAuth hook provided by the library.
I'm looking for a method or workaround to access authentication functionalities in class-based components without converting them to functional components.